# Perl 5.23.3 vs 5.22.0 sub call

Tags: perl

Having this short script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $0;
sub mystat { stat(@_); }

print "perl: $]\n";
print "the $file stats (direct call): @{[ stat($file) ]}\n";
my @statval = mystat($file);
print "the $file stats (mystat call): @statval\n";
```

The above on the perl 5.22 prints the expected (at least by me expected):

```
perl: 5.022000
the mystat stats (direct call): 16777218 28103610 33188 1 501 0 0 230 1443094200 1443094192 1443094192 4096 8
the mystat stats (mystat call): 16777218 28103610 33188 1 501 0 0 230 1443094200 1443094192 1443094192 4096 8
```

using 5.23.3 prints

```
perl: 5.023003
the mystat stats (direct call): 16777218 28103610 33188 1 501 0 0 230 1443094194 1443094192 1443094192 4096 8
the mystat stats (mystat call):
```

What is wrong?

Comment: 5.23 is an unstable development version. It should get fixed before turning into 5.24 - you can file a bug report.

Comment: @choroba understand, just .... returning an list looks like as an very basic thing. :) - but ok - if nothing more is wrong - will delete this question.

Comment: might be related to stat caching rather than returning a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `stat()` doesn't like array passed as arguments, but it works as expected when passing a single scalar,

```
sub mystat { stat($_[0]); }
```

Comment: Which is strange as `stat()` should be agnostic regarding input list?

Comment: accepting - and filling a report on rt ;) thanx. :)

Comment: The change that causes this was introduced in this commit: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/7f399b4008958590740e5bcb61cf22e2cfe5395b

Answer (score 1):

The difference is due to a bug fix.

The following gives `stat`'s prototype:

```
$ perl -E'say prototype("CORE::stat")'
;*
```

As such, `stat`'s argument is suppose to be evaluated in scalar context, which means that

```
stat(@_)
```

is suppose to be equivalent to

```
stat(1)
```

in your example. But for some reason, 5.22 doesn't impose scalar context when it should. This was fixed somewhere between 5.22 and 5.23.3. As such, you'll need to stop relying on this bug and change your code to

```
sub mystat { @_ ? stat($_[0]) : stat() }
```